# Maven installation error in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, maven-plugin

I try to install Maven plugin in Eclipse indigo version 3.7. But I got this error "Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found". The URL that I use is http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases.
What I was wrong! Please Help me.

Thanks

Comment: Indigo is a relatively old release. You should consider to update eclipse. Then you can install plugins over the eclipse marketplace.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I updated eclipse.It's OK.